# How to Play multiple videos simultaneously on iOS with Titanium Studio?

Tags: ios, video, titanium, titanium-modules

I need to play **two or more videos simultaneously** on iOS platform with **Titanium Studio**.

I have tried lots of ways but did not get any proper solution.

I have also tried the **(inic.videoplayer)** module for this. But this is not working for my Scenario. This module only plays a video list in our **Resource Folder**. When I recode any video from device camera or select it from the gallery and want to play it, the module crashes (it does not play the recorded video/the video from the gallery).

On Android I have done it easily:

```
var activeMovie1 = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({ 
    url : videoFile.nativePath, 
    width : "100%",
    mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT, 
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT,
    fullscreen : false, }); 
var activeMovie2 = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({ 
    url : videoFile.nativePath, 
    backgroundColor : 'red', 
    width : "100%", 
    mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT, 
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT, fullscreen : false 
});
```

Please suggest me any way or solution.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: How have you achieved the desired behaviour on Android and why isn't the same prcedure not working on iOS?

Comment: I have create 2 obj for VideoPlayer and add on Window for Android.
var activeMovie1 = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
   url : videoFile.nativePath, 
   width : "100%",
   mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
   scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT,
   fullscreen : false,
  });
var activeMovie2 = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
   url : videoFile.nativePath, 
   backgroundColor : 'red',
   width : "100%",
   mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
   scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT,
   fullscreen : false,
  });

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [sample xcode project](https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/tree/master/AVLoupe) for the multiple video playback using `AVPlayer`. If that approach works for you, you'll need a [Titanium module](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+Development+Guide) built to use `AVPlayer`.